# What are the steps for deducing this pointfree code?

Tags: haskell, pointfree, lifting

I was reviewing some code and came across the following gem, which I'd wager is a copy-paste of `pointfree` output:

(I thought the following would more appropriate than the usual `foo`/`bar` for this particular question :P)

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

data Battleship = Battleship { x :: Int
                             , y :: Int
                             } deriving Show

placeBattleship :: Int -> Int -> Battleship
placeBattleship x' y' = Battleship { x = x', y = y' }

coordinates :: Battleship -> (Int, Int)
coordinates = liftM2 (,) x y
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain the steps needed to simplify from: 
 (i) `coordinates b = (x b, y b)`
 to: 
 (ii) `coordinates = liftM2 (,) x y`? 
 In particular, I'm a bit confused as to the use of `liftM2` as I wasn't even aware that a monad was lurking in the background.

I know that (i) can also be represented as: `coordinates s = (,) (x s) (y s)` but I'm not sure where/how to proceed.

---

P.S.  The following is why I suspect it's from `pointfree` (output is from `GHCI` and `:pl` is aliased to `pointfree`):

```
λ: :pl coordinates s = (x s, y s)
coordinates = liftM2 (,) x y
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This takes advantage of the `Monad` instance for `(->) r`, also called the "reader monad". This is the monad of functions *from* a specific type to `a`. (Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178889/reader-monad-purpose) for motivation on why it exists in the first place.)

To see how it works for various functions, replace `m` with `(r ->` in `m a`. For example, if we just do `liftM`, we get:

```
liftM :: (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)
liftM :: (a -> b) -> ((r -> a) -> (r -> b))
      :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b) -- simplify parentheses
```

...which is just function composition. Neat.

We can do the same thing for `liftM2`:

```
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b) -> (r -> c)
```

So what we see is a way to compose *two* one-argument functions with a two-argument function. It's a way of generalizing normal function composition to more than one argument. The idea is that we create a function that takes a single `r` by passing that through both of the one-argument functions, getting two arguments to pass into the two-argument function. So if we have `f :: (r -> a)`, `g :: (r -> b)` and `h :: (a -> b -> c)`, we produce:

```
\ r -> h (f r) (h r)
```

Now, how does this apply to your code? `(,)` is the two-argument function, and `x` and `y` are one-argument functions of the type `Battleship -> Int` (because that's how field accessors work). With this in mind:

```
liftM2 (,) x y = \ r -> (,) (x r) (y r)
               = \ r -> (x r, y r)
```

Once you've internalized the idea of multiple function composition like this, point-free code like this becomes quite a bit more readable—no need to use the pointfree tool! In this case, I think the non-pointfree version is still better, but the pointfree one isn't terrible itself.

Answer (score 5):

The monad `liftM2` is working over here is the function monad `(->) a`.  This is equivalent to the `Reader` monad, as you may have seen before.

Recall the definition of `liftM2`:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> r) -> m a -> m b -> m r
liftM2 f ma mb = do
    a <- ma
    b <- mb
    return $ f a b
```

So now if we substitute in `(,)` for `f`, `x` for `ma`, and `y` for `mb`, we get

```
liftM2 (,) x y = do
    a <- x
    b <- y
    return $ (,) a b
```

Since `x, y :: Battleship -> Int` which is equivalent to `((->) Battleship) Int`, then `m ~ (->) Battleship`.  The function monad is defined as

```
instance Monad ((->) a) where
    return x = const x
    m >>= f = \a -> f (m a) a
```

Essentially what the function monad does is allow you to extract the output from several functions provided they all have the same input.  A more clear example might be something like

```
test = do
    a <- (^2)
    b <- (^3)
    c <- (^4)
    d <- show
    return (a, b, c, d)

> test 2
(4, 8, 16, "2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily rewrite

```
data Battleship = Battleship { x :: Int
                             , y :: Int
                             } deriving Show

placeBattleship :: Int -> Int -> Battleship
placeBattleship x y = Battleship x y

coordinates :: Battleship -> (Int, Int)
coordinates  (Battleship x y) = (x, y)
```

It isn't point-free style, but quite simple