# Haskell: Problems implementing a simple Monad case study

Tags: haskell, monads

I've began studying Monads by implementing a simple example, but my Monad instance does not compile.

I want to do something like:

```
add5 7 >>= add7
```

This code must return **19** [ (5 + 7) >>=  (12+7) ]

The code i've implemented is:

```
newtype MyType a = MyType ( a -> a)

instance Monad MyType where
    MyType comm  >>= comm2  = MyType (\inp -> let
                                        value = comm inp 
                                        MyType comm2' = comm2
                                        in  comm2' value)
    return  x       = MyType (\input -> input)


add5 :: MyType Integer
add5 = MyType (\inp -> inp + 5)

add7 :: MyType Integer
add7 = MyType (\inp -> inp + 7)
```

When i call `add5` and `add7` without using bind operator (by commenting Monad instance block), it works:

```
main =  do 
        let MyType x = add5
        let MyType y = add7
        putStrLn $ show $ x $ y 7
```

The output errors are:

```
new1.hs:5:94:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            >>= :: MyType a -> (a -> MyType b) -> MyType b
          at new1.hs:4:9
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            >>= :: MyType a -> (a -> MyType b) -> MyType b
          at new1.hs:4:9
    In the first argument of `comm', namely `inp'
    In the expression: comm inp
    In an equation for `value': value = comm inp

new1.hs:6:97:
    Couldn't match expected type `MyType t0'
                with actual type `a -> MyType b'
    In the expression: comm2
    In a pattern binding: MyType comm2' = comm2
    In the expression:
      let
        value = comm inp
        MyType comm2' = comm2
      in comm2' value
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can make a `Monad` instance for that type of endomorphic functions. Removing the `newtype` wrappers, you need to implement a `(>>=)` with the type `(a -> a) -> (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> b)`. You can definitely make a `Monad` instance if you allow the argument type to be independent of the result type though (this would be the Reader monad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually want to do. If you simply want to get the code sample

```
add5 7 >>= add7
```

to work and produce a result of `19` by adding the numbers in the "obvious" way, then it is simple, and *any* monad will do. We can thus pick the simplest possible monad, the "identity" monad:

```
newtype Id a = Id { runId :: a }

instance Monad Id where
  return x   = Id x
  Id x >>= f = f x
```

Note that this code will produce warnings in GHC 7.8, because in the future, `Applicative` will become a superclass of monad and you'll have to define additional instances. For this example, they're irrelevant, so I'll omit them.

Now you can define `add5` and `add7`:

```
add5 :: Id Int
add5 n = return (n + 5)

add7 :: Id Int
add7 n = return (n + 7)
```

If you omit the type signatures and ask GHCi, you'll see that both definition actually have the more general type `(Num a, Monad m) => a -> m a`. That's what I mean by saying that your example works for *any* monad.

You can try that it all works in GHCi:

```
GHCi> :t add5 7 >>= add7 
add5 7 >>= add7 :: Id Int
GHCi> runId (add5 7 >>= add7)
19
```

Answer (score 4):

It cannot be a `Monad`, because it is not even a `Functor`, since you have a type variable in the contravariant position.

This means you cannot implement:

```
fmap :: (a->b)->MyType a->MyType b
```

You can use `f :: a->b` to change the type of result in `a->a` to `a->b`, but you can't change the type of the argument to that function to get `b->b`, which is needed to construct `MyType b`.

Comment: Yes you can implement `fmap`. My first revision of my answer was almost yours. But `fmap f (MyType g) = MyType id` typechecks. The `id` functor law is violated, though.

Comment: @Franky that's a useless implementation. You could have just as well called it `Const`. And you can always plug `undefined`, too. The point is that it must work for any `a->a`.

Comment: That `fmap` implementation is just as useless as the OP's `return`.

Comment: @Franky I think your suggestion is worse, because it really asserts that any `a` _as a type_ can be mapped into `a->a` _as a type_ - but only one point in `a->a` "behaves well".

Comment: @Franky Put in other words, if you have a category with objects `a->a`, there are some arrows between them. What is their composition? Then embed it back into `Hask`. Your `fmap` must "hit" that composition, too, when mapping the composition of functions. You may want to pretend it is a `const`, but I am not convinced; you'd need to show the composition of arrows between `a->a` first.

Comment: I don't really understand. Am I right that your `a` is actually the `b` of `fmap :: (a -> b)...`? That `id` in `fmap _ _ = MyType id` is of type `b -> b`, making the result `MyType b`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65752/discussion-between-franky-and-sassa-nf).

Answer (score 3):

You are on the wrong track. `MyType` cannot be a monad.
The only monad instance implementation possible for `MyType` will be fairly trivial, and not able to make `add5 7 >>= add7` equal `19`.

`>>=` must have type

```
MyType a -> (a -> MyType b) -> MyType b -- remove newType
(a -> a) -> (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> b)
```

The only function that typechecks is

```
(MyType _) >>= _  = MyType (\input -> input)
```

which looks very similar to your `return` implemention. We usually write `id` instead of `(\input -> input)` in haskell.

Why do I claim this is the only function?
Check the simplified type signature `(a -> a) -> (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> b)` again: Without an `a` as input, the arguments of `>>=`, `a -> a` and `a -> (b -> b)`, cannot be evaluated.

This does not satisfy the monad laws: `x >>= return = x`

```
MyType (\x -> x + 1) >>= return
 =MyType id
/=MyType (\x -> x + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need monads for what you are trying to do. Instead you can use the [Arrows](https://www.haskell.org/arrows/):

```
Prelude> :m + Control.Arrow
Prelude Control.Arrow> let add5 = (+5)
Prelude Control.Arrow> let add7 = (+7)
Prelude Control.Arrow> let add12 = add5 >>> add7
Prelude Control.Arrow> add12 7
19
```

The `(>>>)` function is just the composition operator (i.e. `(.)`) with its arguments flipped, for function instances. Hence you could just as simply do:

```
Prelude> let add5 = (+5)
Prelude> let add7 = (+7)
Prelude> let add12 = add7 . add5
Prelude> add12 7
19
```

There's already a monad instance for functions. It's called the reader monad: [What is the purpose of the Reader Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14178889/783743).

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return x = \_ -> x
    f >>= g = \x -> g (f x) x
```

It allows you to things like:

```
a2-minus-b2 = \a -> do
    a-minus-b <- (\b -> a - b)
    a-plus-b  <- (\b -> a + b)
    return (a-minus-b * a-plus-b)
```

Ofcourse it would be better just to write it as:

```
a2-minus-b2 = \a b -> (a - b) * (a + b)
```

However, I just wanted to show you what the reader monad can be used to do.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that `Reader` and Monad instance for functions are completely irrelevant. (IOW, this answer is largely nonsense)