# ReaderT static environment

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

> Declaration of the `ReaderT` monad transformer, which adds a static environment to a given monad.

What does it mean to add a static environment to a given monad?

Someone suggested that this is a duplicate to another question. I believe that this question is unique because I'm asking what it means to have a static environment and also my question pertains to ReaderT. Even if it is similar to Reader, they are still different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reader Monad Purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178889/reader-monad-purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the environment cannot be updated: you can only *read* from it (hence the name of `ReaderT`). This is in contrast to monad transformers like `StateT` which provide you an environment you can both read and write to.

---

Inside a reader monad, you can reach the envionment using the [`ask`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:ask) function:

```
ask :: Monad m => ReaderT r m r
```

Inside a state monad, you have a similar function for reading called [`get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:get) as well as another function which writes to the state called [`put`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:put):

```
get :: Monad m => StateT s m s 
put :: Monad m => s -> StateT s m ()
```

#### Examples

Here is a sample usage of both `ReaderT` and `StateT`. Let's suppose my underlying monad will be `IO` so that I will be able to print things along the way.

The contrived example here is a number guessing program - the environment is just a number that you are trying to guess (so `Int`). `guess` takes a number and checks whether the number is the same one as the one in the environment. If not, it prints a message to the screen. In either case, it returns whether your guess was successful.

```
guessReader :: Int -> ReaderT Int IO Bool
guessReader guess = do
  actual <- ask
  if guess == actual
    then return True
    else do
      lift $ putStrLn ("The number was " ++ show actual)
      return False
```

However, suppose now you want a way of changing the number you are trying to guess randomly after a guess. Then, since you need to change the environment, you will need to use `StateT`.

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)

guessState :: Int -> StateT Int IO Bool
guessState guess = do
   actual <- get
   if guess == actual
     then return True
     else do
       lift $ putStrLn ("The number was " ++ show actual)
       newActual <- lift $ randomRIO (0,10)
       put newActual
       return False
```

Then, if you run the reader version several times, note that the value you are trying to guess never changes. That is not the case with the state version, which resets to a new number every time you make a wrong guess:

```
ghci> runReaderT (guessReader 3 >> guessReader 4 >> guessReader 5) 5
The number was 5
The number was 5
True
ghci> evalStateT (guessState 3 >> guessState 4 >> guessState 5) 5
The number was 5
The number was 6
The number was 2
False
```

Comment: Can I reach this environment?

Comment: Is it that if I want the environment I need to do <- ask?

Comment: An example of usage should be given to let the OP better understand what you are talking about. Types don't talk by themselves to beginners, this is important to remember...

Comment: @Alec thank you for taking the time to write that up!