# Understanding this simple Reader monad example

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to understand the Reader monad, and I'm following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179721/10116440 which has this example:

```
 import Control.Monad.Reader

 data GameState = NotOver | FirstPlayerWin | SecondPlayerWin | Tie

 data Game position
   = Game {
           getNext :: position -> [position],
           getState :: position -> GameState
          }

 getNext' :: position -> Reader (Game position) [position]
 getNext' position
   = do game <- ask
        return $ getNext game position

 getState' :: position -> Reader (Game position) GameState
 getState' position
   = do game <- ask
        return $ getState game position


 negamax :: Double -> position -> Reader (Game position) Double
 negamax color position
     = do state <- getState' position 
          case state of
             FirstPlayerWin -> return color
             SecondPlayerWin -> return $ negate color
             Tie -> return 0
             NotOver -> do possible <- getNext' position
                           values <- mapM ((liftM negate) . negamax (negate color)) possible
                           return $ maximum values
```

The first thing I don't understand is `return $ getNext game position`. `getNext`, when applied to a `game`, returns `position -> [position]`. This, when applied to `position`, returns `[position]`. So the line `return $ getNext game position` should returng something other than `Reader (Game position) [position]`, I don't know which this something is, because I don't know how the `return` is defined for the `Reader` monad.

Anyways, which "instance" of the `Game` will `ask` return? I don't understand, there's none in this code. Also, `runReader` is never called, so what are the `Reader` results of `getNext`, `getState` and `negamax` used for?

Could someone complete this example with how would `runReader` actually be run in this code, and which `game` instance is returned by `ask`?

Also, why `Reader env a` and not simply `Reader a`?

Comment: You ask, "why `Reader env a` and not simply `Reader a`?". Let me turn it back on you: suppose we run with the `Reader a` idea; what is your proposal for the RHS of `data Reader a = {- ... -}`?

Answer (score 3):

There is a plenty of questions in your post – this is quite against StackOverflow rules. Nevertheless, I will answer them one by one:

#### Why `return $ getNext game position`

Indeed, `getNext game position` returns something of type `[position]`. Now take a look at the `return` **function** — its type is `Monad m => a -> m a`. In this case `m` is `Reader (Game position)` (not `Reader (Game position) a`, nor just `Reader`! `Reader` itself isn't a Monad. `Reader something` is). If you instantiate `a` to `[position]` (as applied) you will get `Reader (Game position) [position]` as declared.

#### Which "instance" of the `Game` will `ask` return?

`ask` is a utility coming from `Control.Monad.Reader`. Generally speaking, `Reader` is a monad that handles some environment under the hood. `ask :: Reader env env` is an action that just results in that environment. For example

```
runReader ask 123 == 123
```

So, answering your question, it will return the currently handled `game` that is hidden under the `Reader`'s coat.

#### Could someone complete this example

I don't know what do you mean by "complete" here, but sample usage of `runReader`:

```
runReader (negamax 1.0 123) Game{getNext = \x -> [x], getState = \x -> NotOver}
```

#### Why `Reader env a` and not simply `Reader a`

Because `Reader env` describes a computation with a "background" value of type `env`. This would make no sense without `env` – the point of `Reader` is to have that value and its type needs to be known. If you don't like writing it every time in your case you may write

```
type GameMonad position = Reader (Game position)
```